# Rave Raraport - динамическая таблица

Tags: ravereport

Вопрос в следующем. В Rave Raport создал отчёт. Расположил всё как надо.
Расположил DataMemo. Но вот как сделать оформление его, так и не пойму.
DataMemo ведь меняет динамически высоту, в зависимости от контента.
А вот как сделать его обрамление (линиями или прямоугольником), чтобы оно было тоже взаимно динамическим, ни как не пойму.
По всем правилам должна же быть такая реализация в Rave Raport?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(рис. 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.
В свойстве `Anchor` компанента `Rectangle`необходимо выставить параметр такого рода: `(V-Stretch / Left)`